# Removing hard-coded subtitles or Logo in videos

Tags: video

How do I remove hard-coded (or merged) subtitles or logo in a videos files?

Comment: Do you want to remove the box that contains the logo, white out those pixels, crop the video... What OS are you using?

Comment: @soandos, Thanks for asking. I wanted the box to be remove or blurred. The OS would be Windows (most prefer) follow by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot remove them, the best you can do is to …

- Crop them out, crop the area that they are in mostly (like the lowest 2 lines), this is terrible looking.
- Clone them away with a [logoaway type algorithm](http://compression.ru/video/logo_removal/index_en.html). The blurry attempted replacement clones surrounding parts of the video into the block area , and it is just about as bad as the texts staying there.

[image: before]
[image: after]

- Try and threshold [clone blur them away](http://www.compression.ru/video/subtitles_removal/userguide_en.html), again you cannot bring back the video that is behind them.

I find that any of the methods are not an improvement over learning a second language :-). When the picture moves behind them, the cloned blurred out mess there changes to try and "fix" it, whereas the subs themselves are more solid, and easier to ignore.

All of the above methods are also going to require a full decode and re-encode of the video, so it takes a fair amount of time  The whole video is either going to look worse from the digital generation loss, or the file size is going to be bigger – because all high compressed video suffers from de-re-compressing, unless it is left more uncompressed.

Comment: As shown in pictures of the link you given - The logoaway was quite awesome. However, I think the subtitles_removal have room for improvement.

Comment: Yes the pictures are not moving.  I should have said Simple corner logo removal is not to distracting. and transparent logos like say the NBC logo 1/2 transparent  , goes away easily, but then it is not obnoxious to begin with.

Comment: Anyway, still a +1 vote to you. If I could not find any better answer this few days, I will vote your solution as the final answer.

Comment: I think this is *the* answer, so +1 for that. There aren't really any other options.